# vba loop through all objects within a word document

Tags: vba, excel, loops, ms-word

I need to loop through all objects within a Word document to find all tables and copy paste them into an Excel sheet. Problem is that some of the tables are within shapes. So I ended up with writing one loop for tables and one for the tables in shapes. So now I have them unordered in my Excel sheet of course. But for my final solution I need to order both (the tables and the tables in shapes) into the right order like they appear in the Word document.

Does anyone has some suggestions. Even small hints are welcome after googling the whole day

What I have so far with two Loops:

```
Dim Appwd As Word.Application
Set Appwd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Appwd.Visible = True
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdDoc = Appwd.Documents.Open("U:\path\to\test.docx")

Dim Tb As Table
Dim Shp As Object
Dim tab_anz As Integer 
Dim lz As Integer 
Dim i As Integer
lz = 1

For Each Tb In wdDoc.Tables
    Tb.range.Copy
    Sheets(1).Cells(lz + 2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    lz = Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Next Tb


For Each Shp In wdDoc.Shapes
    With Shp.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
            Sheets(1).Cells(lz + 2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            lz = Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        End If
    End With
    DoEvents
Next Shp
```

What kind it should look like:

```
For Each Object In WordDocument.Objects
    If Object.type == Table Then
        Copy into Excel sheet
    Elseif Object.type == Shapes
        If Table in Shape Then copy into Excel sheet
    End If  ' Only for tables or tables in shapes
Next Object
```

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve]. Your question is currently rather unclear.

Comment: I've edit my problem description

Comment: Is there a way to call all objects in a Word document (this is what I mean with WordDocument.Objects) to loop through them and check if it is a table or shape?

Comment: No one has any hints or suggestions? Or is there still something unclear?